# How do I prevent tycho-p2-repository-plugin from including target platform dependencies?

Tags: tycho

I am trying to create a P2 repository using Tycho for a plugin that extends the Eclipse environment.  When I try to do a mvn install, the zip file it creates adds the plugins from org.eclipse which I do not want included.

I have already defined the plugin not to include dependencies (even though the default was already false)

```
  <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
                  <includeAllDependencies>false</includeAllDependencies>
          </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

At the moment it creates a zip file of at least 48MB.

Answer (score 3):

The p2 repository built by the eclipse-repository packaging type only contains (transitive) inclusions of the module's `category.xml` and `*.product` files. "Transitive inclusion" is everything listed in these files, and everything included in the included features. By default, artifacts that are only referenced (e.g. in the bundle manifests) are *not* included.

So if the p2 repository contains too many artifacts, simply don't include the artifacts, or the features containing the artifacts.

In case you want to build an RCP that has to include certain things that should not go into the p2 repository, move the product definition into a separate `eclipse-repository` module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-feature-distribution</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir
                                dir="${basedir}/target/${project.parent.artifactId}/${feature.version}" />
                            <!-- Copy core and targetPlatform jars -->
                            <copy
                                todir="${basedir}/target/${project.parent.artifactId}/${feature.version}">
                                <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/repository/plugins">
                                    <exclude name="ch.qos.logback.slf4j*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="javax.xml.bind*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.apache.xerces*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.apache.xml.resolver*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.apache.xml.serializer*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.equinox.common*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.equinox.ds*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.equinox.util*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.osgi.services*.jar" />
                                    <exclude name="org.eclipse.osgi*.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                            </copy>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```